# How do I save VB6 code, ie. the extension, which will open as macro in Excel? Not code created with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

How do I save VB6 code, ie. the extension, which will open as macro in Excel? Not code created with VBA in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Modules` in Visual Basic 6.  The extension is `.bas` and you can open these in VBA.